# bases of two right triangles inscribed in a semicircle forming the hypotenuse of a larger right triangle?

Tags: geometry

I'm unsure why the largest triangle with hypotenuse $r_a + r_b$ must be a right triangle. This is a stepping stone to proving that the area of the 2 smaller circles subtracted from the largest circle is $\pi$. The 3 circles are all tangent to one another and the perpendicular line of length 2 is a given.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWF20.png)

Source: http://datagenetics.com/blog/january62019/index.html

Comment: I am puzzled by the wording.  "Hypotenuse $r_a+ r_b$ must be a right triangle".  Only right triangles **have** hypotenuses!

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what your question is. The large red triangle is a right triangle since it is inscribed in a semicircle. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a well-known result that an angle $\angle ABC$ will be a right angle if and only if points $A,B,C$ are inscribed in a semicircle with $A$ and $C$ endpoints of its diameter.

Pf:  If $A,B,C$ are inscribed in a semicircle with $A$ and $C$ as enpoints of its diameter and $O$ the center of the circle than $AO = BO=CO$ so $\triangle AOB$ and $\triangle BOC$ are isosceles And $\angle OAB \cong \angle OBA$ and $\angle OBC \cong \angle OCB$.  And so as $180 = m\angle CAB + m\angle ABC + m\angle ACB$ and $m\angle CAB = m\angle OAB =m\angle OBA$ and $m\angle ABC = m\angle OBA + m\angle OBC$ and $m\angle ACB= m\angle OCB=m\angle OBC$ we have $180 = 2m\angle OBA + 2m\angle OCB$.  So $m\angle ABC = m\angle OBA + m\angle OCB = 90$.

If $\angle ABC$ is a right angle.  Than $\angle BAC$ and $\angle ACB$ are complementary and accute.  Construct $M$ on $\overline AC$ so that $m\angle ABM =  m\angle MAB$.  Then as $\angle MBC$ is complimentary to $\angle MBA \cong \angle MAB = \angle CAB$ and $\angle MCB = \angle ACB$ is complimentary to $\angle MBC$ have $m\angle MCB = m\angle MBC$.  So $\triangle AMB$ and $\triangle BMC$ are isosceles and $AM = BM$ and $BM = MC$ so $AM = BM = CM$.  So $A,B,C$ are points of a circle centered at $M$.  As $A,M, C$ are colinear, $\overline{AC}$ is a diameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an inscribed angle in a circle, the arc subtended by the angle is twice the angle.

The bottom line is a diameter of the big circle (half of which is shown).

Can you complete the thought from here?

Spoiler:

> A diameter cuts a circle into two halves of $\pi$ radians. The inscribed angle must be half this, or $\pi/2$ radians.

Answer (score 0):

An angle inscribed in a circle will always have a measure of one half of the intercepted arc.

The largest angle in the largest triangle intercepts a $180^\circ $ arc (since we know we have three semicircles).  Therefore, the inscribed angle opposite this $180^\circ $ intercepted arc has half that measure: $90^\circ $.